# How to make specific grid layout in swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, gridview, grid

How can I make grid layout as following in swiftUI?

I tried with LazyVStack & ZStack but not find properly as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a series of nested `HStack`s and `VStack`s. Make the views squares by `aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<4) { _ in Square() }
            }
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Square()
                    Square()
                }
                Square()
                VStack {
                    Square()
                    Square()
                }
            }
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<4) { _ in Square() }
            }
        }
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct Square: View {
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle().stroke()
            .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

In your screenshot, the squares seem to have a larger vertical spacing than horizontal spacing. That can be achieved by adding different `(spacing: ...)` parameters to `VStack`s and `HStack`s.